# Proper Microformats for a 1-100 and or a 1-10 rating

Tags: json-ld, microformats, user-reviews

Has anyone used a 1-100 rating system with Microformats and seen it work in SERPS?

I expect that a `<div class="rating">50</div>` would produce a 2.5 star rating on the result snippet but am hoping for any experience.

Would it be unadvisable to use a 1-100 rating with microformats? If that's the case I could do some backend work to do the math on the rating to expose a 1-5 rating within some JSONLD markup.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    { "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Business",
        "name": "Joe Businessman",
        "telephone": "(174)222-1012",
        "description": "desc",
        "aggregateRating":
        {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "2.5",
            "reviewCount": "30"
        }
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
I received an awesome answer! But also for others: [Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews)

> "Ratings that don't use a 5-point scale: By default, Google assumes
>   that your site uses a 5-point scale, where 5 is the best possible
>   rating and 1 is the worst, but you can use any other scale. If you do,
>   you can mark up the best and worst ratings, and Google will scale that
>   to the 5-star system used in rich snippets."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google supports a wide range of `ratingValues` should it be 1-5, 1-6, 1-10 or even a 1000. You do however have to use `bestRating` since Google assumes 5 by default. It's very flexible and can even start from zero, one or even ten using `worstRating`.

> [*1-100 Example on Schema AggregateRating*](http://schema.org/AggregateRating#eg-11)
>
> ```
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {
>   "@context": "http://schema.org",
>   "@type": "Product",
>   "aggregateRating": {
>     "@type": "AggregateRating",
>     "bestRating": "100",
>     "ratingCount": "24",
>     "ratingValue": "87"
>   },
>   "image": "dell-30in-lcd.jpg",
>   "name": "Dell UltraSharp 30\" LCD Monitor",
>   "offers": {
>     "@type": "AggregateOffer",
>     "highPrice": "$1495",
>     "lowPrice": "$1250",
>     "offerCount": "8",
>     "offers": [
>       {
>         "@type": "Offer",
>         "url": "save-a-lot-monitors.com/dell-30.html"
>       },
>       {
>         "@type": "Offer",
>         "url": "jondoe-gadgets.com/dell-30.html"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> </script>
> ```

Since Google only will display upto 5 stars you will find that they will convert your scoring to the 5 star system, but it will have a text entry to the right of it.

*This would look something like this:*

[image]

Google also supports using percentages between 1-100, as seen on Rotten Tomatoes.

*Some more examples include:*

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I've updated my answer with the Google page that explains this as well should it help others.